# How to use different JMX domain names when duplicate doamins allowed in Infinispan L2 cache

Tags: hibernate, jmx, infinispan

I am using Infinispan L2 cache and I have two application nodes. The two apps are not identical and currently I am using following configurations.

```
<global> 
<globalJmxStatistics enabled="true" cacheManagerName="H2L"   jmxDomain="org.infinispan" allowDuplicateDomains="true"/>
---------
---------
</global>
```

Generated MBeans are org.infinispan and org.infinspan1 . I need to rename them with customized names, for an example : *MerchantResponder* and *BMA* .

I am using Tomcat 6, Hibernate 4 and Spring 3.5. I have tried to set global configuartion programatically by using following code but I was unable to do what I am expected.

```
GlobalConfiguration glob = new GlobalConfigurationBuilder()

        .nonClusteredDefault().globalJmxStatistics().enable()

        .jmxDomain("MerchantResponder")

        .build();
```

I don't want to create new JMX Doamins , I just need to rename already created Domains.

Comment: You can't configure the Hibernate 2LC cache programmatically. It's all about the settings in the configuration file passed via the infinsipan config property. Normally, you'd set each configuration to have different cacheManagerName, but just giving each configuration a different jmxDomain value should just work. Either enable TRACE logging or hook up a debugger to see what's really being used. org.infinispan.jmx.CacheManagerJmxRegistration is the class you wanna be debugging.

Answer (score 0):

I do not have rept to comment you answer. Don't Infinispan has a way to edit infinispan.xml in programatically ? I think Infinispan has a way to edit the XMl file programatically. If so should be able to change the JMX domain programatically. Thanks

Comment: I don't believe infinispan has a way to edit the configuration for a running cache programmatically, unless you count the JMX console, which is *very* limited in what you can do (I don't count it). However, you can define the configuration for a cache programmatically, then start it.

Comment: Shadow I am with you. I do not think it's possible to change a running cache configuration programmatically.  I think it should be possible to take a configuration file programtically as a parameter to the caching configuration builder then overwrite, add, edit configuration and then start the cache.